# What's the counterpart of RSpecs instance_double in Minitest?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, minitest

I'm searching for the "minitest-way" to double expensive objects in a safe manner.

I know mocks, stubs and use them, but the problem is that simple doubles are not waterproof. If the api of the real objects change, the tests pass, but the real implementation fails.

I found rspec's instance_double-feature. I create my tests with Minitest. Can you point me in the right direction?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minitest is designed intentionally to have very rudimentary implementations of mocks and stubs. Following link could be interesting: https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html.

So conclusion is that there's no truly counterpart of rspec's instance_double at Minitest.

In the meantime I'm a fan of classical testing. That means: try to avoid mocks as much as possible. But there are cases where mocking is inevitable. If that is the case I would recommend the minitest integration of respec-mocks: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/outside-rspec/integrate-with-minitest